# Avoiding duplicate if statements inside and outside a lock

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-4.0, thread-safety

The below code is a very simplified example of what I am trying to accomplish.

```
 private object _highestLevelLock = new object();
    private int _highestValue;
    private void SetHighestValue()
    {
        var random = new Random();
        var next = random.Next(0, 100);
        if (next > _highestValue)
        {
            lock (_highestLevelLock)
            {
                if(next > _highestValue)
                    _highestValue = next;
            }
        }
    }
```

Namely, I have a variable that holds the highest integer that I have come across so far. SetHighestValue() can be accessed by multiple threads.

If the random integer generated is larger than the currently largest integer, I will update the _highestValue.

My question is, how can I avoid checking twice if next > highestValue? If I remove it from inside the lock, then there is the risk that _highestValue will get set to something even higher, before this thread sets the value, and in this scenario, _highestValue will be inaccurate.

I know that I can get rid of the if statement outside the lock, but I do not want to lock unnecessarily.

Is there a better way to accomplish this? Potentially some combination of locking and/or using the Interlocked namespace?

On a somewhat related note, should _highestValue be volatile? Even if so, I assume that will not help with my question at hand.

Thanks!

Comment: The lock is not unnecessary. If you may need to modify the object, you need the lock. Just acquire the lock outside the first `if`. Do you have any sense of how often the call will result in a change?

Comment: I don't think you can really avoid it in this case... [double-check locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_check_locking) is a common pattern, and it's a good fit here.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, the reason there is a check outside the lock is to avoid locking unnecessarily... locking is expensive

Comment: @ThomasLevesque: Locking is not expensive, that's a myth. It's contention that is expensive.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, that's what I meant to say, but I didn't express it very well... thanks for the precision.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque: Well, that kind of undercuts your case because the contention is pretty much the same with or without the lock. (Although it's hard to be sure without understanding the access pattern. This actually looks like premature optimization, unless the OP knows things about the access pattern he hasn't shared.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing is a case of [test and test and set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_and_Test-and-set) and is a very efficient way of handling things. To answer your question, short of encapsulating your condition in a function there is no way to get rid of the code duplication.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the [`Interlocked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/801kt583.aspx) class instead of locking:
Each thread with a higher value tries to perform the update, but re-checks if it fails:

```
var next = random.Next(0, 100);
int current = _highestValue;
bool updated = false;
while(next > current && !updated)
{
    updated = Interlocked.Exchange(ref _highestValue, next, current);
    current = _highestValue;
}
```

Comment: Yep. +1ed then withdrew when I saw the race

Comment: The if statement setting the bool are not atomic so I don't think this is any different from what I posted.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - Well if a thread with a higher value tries to update then it can re-check and re-try. I assume this code executes in a loop or some kind. If each thread attempts once, then yes this won't work.

Comment: @user981225 - The update is atomic so if the update fails then the current highest has changed.

Comment: @Lee: Right, but it may be changed to something that is or isn't higher than what this thread is trying to change it to. You want: `int current = _highestValue; while (next > current) { Interlocked.Exchange(ref _highestValue, next, current); current = _HighestValue; }` (You can break if Interlocked.Exchange succeeds if you want.) Since this is a pretty minimal function that's perfectly suitable for this purpose, it's likely to be very close to optimum.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - Ok I've updated my answer to include the repeated check.